# SSRS doesn't color the cell when no data (IsNothing)

Tags: reporting-services

I cannot fill the cell's background color in SSRS when there is no data in that cell.

(Please, see the link to the screenshot below).

My stored procedure returns three columns:
"Month Year";
"Contact Type";
"Contact count".

I use column groups to show "Month Year" as a column. And row groups to show  "Contact Type" as a row.

I want to fill back color of the row to Grey when "Contact Type" = "Total number of contacts".

I use expression:

```
    =IIf(InStr(Fields!ContactType.Value,"Total") > 0, "LightGrey", "Transparent")
```

But the problem is that when there was no activity in this month, the cell gets no value (=IsNothing). In this case I replaced it with zero.

But the cell with zero stays "Transparent".

I understand that this is because there is no value for ContactType field as well.

But is there any tricky workaround?

#### This is the screenshot how my report looks like

[image: This is the screenshot how my report looks like]

Please help me to color cells with no data!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's right, you cannot check the value of something that does not exist. And if the ContactType for September does not exist in the query result, there is nothing you can do in SSRS with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you just have the (**strictly superior**) instead of (**equal to or superior than 0**)
try the use of this expression:

```
=IIf(InStr(Fields!ContactType.Value,"Total") **>=** 0, "LightGrey", "Transparent")
```

instead of:

```
  =IIf(InStr(Fields!ContactType.Value,"Total") > 0, "LightGrey", "Transparent")
```

Comment: And if it doesn't work just let  me know so I can help you using another expression

Comment: =IIf(InStr(Fields!ContactType.Value,"Total") >= 0, "LightGrey", "Transparent")

Comment: there is no row "total"+"September 2009" in the result set. So I cannot check the value of ContactType for September because this row is absent in my query. You cannot check the value of something that does not exist...

Comment: could you provide me with more informations such as the result of your query and fields of your databse

Comment: "Month Year"; "Contact Type"; "Contact count"; "Branch".

Comment: "June 2006"; "Individual Assessment"; "1"; "Branch 1".
"December 2017"; "Group Contact"; "6"; "Branch 1".
"May 2005"; "Group Contact"; "2"; "Branch 1".
"June 2006"; "Total number of contacts"; "1"; "Branch 1".
"December 2017"; "Total number of contacts"; "6"; "Branch 1".
"May 2005"; "Total number of contacts"; "2"; "Branch 1".

Comment: "September 2009"; "Individual Assessment"; "3"; "Branch 2".
"September 2009"; "Total number of contacts"; "3"; "Branch 2".

Comment: I use row grouping in ssrs to separate them by branches. At the screenshot I showed only results for Branch1.

In Branch 1 I have NO results for "September 2009", but when I use column grouping by "Month Year" I get empty cell for Branch1 September 2009.

In my result set I have many rows with "Contact Type" = "Total number of contacts".

And I want all the rows where "Contact Type" like "Total" to become Grey.

For branch 1 there is no SQL result rows for "September 2009", so I cannot check the value of "Contact Type" for "September 2009", when I paint it, because it does not exist.

Comment: I've provided you with the info